# Jmeter : How to perform load testing on AngularJS based web application?

Tags: angularjs, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am unable to perform load test angularjs based web-application. Please share suggestion and example if there is any.

If we can not perform load test on angularjs using jmeter then please suggest any tool or any approach.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Load testing tools are [backend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_and_back_ends#Back-end_focused)-[agnostic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agnosticism), to wit they don't "know" anything regarding underlying technologies stack of the web application.

Just remember one simple requirement: load test must represent real life application usage. It means that each JMeter thread (virtual user) need to impersonate a real user using a real browser and accessing your application.

Real browsers in their turn don't do any magic, they just send [HTTP Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) and render the responses. JMeter doesn't actually "render" the response, JMeter waits for the response and measures the time taken.

So the answer is **YES**, you can use JMeter (as well as any other testing tool) for load testing an Angular web application, just make sure that load pattern generated by JMeter matches the one which real browser generates.

The most tricky thing is implementing [AJAX requests](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp), due to their asynchronous nature they're incompatible with JMeter threads model therefore if your application relies on AJAX technology you will need to precisely mimic AJAX calls as well. You can use [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter) for this  (Parallel Controller is not an integral part of JMeter distribution, it's a plugin which can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/))